# Entity Framework Core 2.0 SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I get an exception when trying to seed the database:

> SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Grades_Students_StudentId". The conflict occurred in database "GradeBookDB", table "dbo.Students", column 'Id'.

My code:

```
if (context.Students.Any())
{
    return;
}

var students = new List<Student>()
        {
            new Student()
            {
                FirstName = "John",
                LastName = "Smith"

                Subjects = new List<Subject>()
                {
                    new Subject()
                    {
                        Name = "Math",

                        Grades = new List<Grade>()
                        {
                            new Grade()
                            {
                                Value = 4
                            }
                        }
                    },
                }
            },
        };

context.Students.AddRange(students);
context.SaveChanges();
```

I created migration from these models:

```
public class Student
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Subject> Subjects { get; set; } = new List<Subject>();
}

public class Subject
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Grade> Grades { get; set; } = new List<Grade>();
}

public class Grade
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public double Value { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SubjectId")]
    public Subject Subject { get; set; }

    public Guid SubjectId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("StudentId")]
    public Guid StudentId { get; set; }

    public Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I have no idea why I am getting an exception because when I delete FK (`StudentId`) from the `Grade` class and add FK (`StudentId`) to the `Subject` class, everything is working and there is no exception.

Comment: You should remove those `[ForeignKey]`. First, because they aren't needed because you are following Convention over Configuration. Second, you applied them incorrectly

Comment: Could You please explain me why they are applied incorrectly?

Comment: The first one points `Subject` to `SubjectId`, which is correct. The second points `StudentId` to `StudentId`, instead of to `Student`

Comment: So I have to switch their places? public Student  Student should be above the public Guid StudentId? I did it but still have the same excetion. :(

Comment: The model is wrong anyway. Because of the `Student.Subjects` collection navigation property, the `Subject` already has FK `StudentId` even if you don't define it explicitly (a so called shadow property). Hence either `Grade` should not have `Student` relation, or `Student` should not have `Subjects`. It's unclear what type of relationships are you trying to model.

Comment: I am begginer, could you recommend me what I should learn to know more about stuff u just mentioned like( navigation property, FK , shadow property, relationships (many to many) is it SQL  or Entityframework knowledge?